# Show weighted estimator is unbiased when sampling from a finite population

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Given a finite population of $N$ units {$(U_1, X_1),\ldots,(U_N, X_N)$}, with $X_i$ being the observation associated with the $i$-th unit $U_i$, consider estimating
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\mu=\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N X_i,
$$ the population mean.

We can find the variance of the sample mean $\bar{X}$ based on a simple random sample of size $n$ from the population, given by
$$
\Var\bar{X}=\frac{N-n}{N-1} \frac{\sigma^2}{n},
$$ where $\sigma^2=\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N (X_i -\mu))^2$ is the population variance.

I know how to prove this. But I don't know how to solve the following problems:

*For a sampling design where $\pi_i$ is the probability of the ith unit being included in a sample, show the following*:

1. $\delta_S=\sum_{i \in S} X_i/\pi_i$ is unbiased for $N\mu$,
2. The variance of $\delta_S$ has the following expression
   $$
   \Var(\delta_S)=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 \left(\frac{1}{\pi_i}-1\right) + \sum_{i=1}^N  \sum_{j(\neq j)=1}^N X_i X_j \left(\frac{\pi_{ij}}{\pi_i \pi_j}-1\right),
   $$ where $\pi_{ij}$ is the probability of both $X_i$ and $X_j$ being included in a sample.

**My try**: I started to calculate the expectation of $\delta_S$ and I got the following result
$$
\begin{split}
E(\delta_S) & = E\left(\sum_{i \in S} X_i/\pi_i\right) =\sum_{i \in S} E(X_i/\pi_i) \\
& =\sum_{i \in S} \frac{1}{\pi_i} E(X_i) =\sum_{i \in S} \frac{1}{\pi_i} \mu =\mu \sum_{i \in S} \frac{1}{\pi_i}.
\end{split}
$$ Unfortunately, this is not $N\mu$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @angryavian I update my attempt.

Comment: The sampled set $S$ is random, so you can't move the expectation into the summation in the way you did.

Comment: Did you try using law of total expectation? This can help when you have a random variable inside another random variable.
$$E\left[\sum_{i\in S} \frac{X_i}{\pi_i} \right] = E_S\left[E_X\left[\sum_{i\in S} \frac{X_i}{\pi_i} \; \Bigg| \; S \right]\right]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z_i$ be $1$ if unit $i$ is included in the sample, and $0$ otherwise. Note that $P(Z_i=1)=E[Z_i]=\pi_i$.

Another tricky thing is that **the $X_i$ here are considered non-random**, since you are given a fixed population of size $N$ from which you are sampling. [For instance, note that the expression for the variance of $\delta_S$ is given in terms of $X_i$.]

The statistic $\delta_S$ can be rewritten as $\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i X_i / \pi_i$. Then
$$E[\delta_S] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[Z_i X_i / \pi_i] = \sum_{i=1}^N E[Z_i] X_i/\pi_i = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i = N\mu.$$

Note that the last step comes directly from the definition of $\mu := \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$.

---

For random variables $U$ and $V$ we have $\text{Var}(U+V) = \text{Var}(U) + \text{Var}(V) + \text{Cov}(U, V) + \text{Cov}(V, U)$. Generalizing this to a sum of $N$ random variables, we have
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(\delta_S)
&= \text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i X_i / \pi_i\right)
\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^N \text{Var}(Z_i X_i / \pi_i)
+ \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j \ne i} \text{Cov}(Z_i X_i / \pi_i, Z_j X_j / \pi_j).
\end{align}

We have
$$\text{Var}(Z_i) = E[Z_i^2] - E[Z_i]^2 = \pi_i - \pi_i^2$$
and
$$\text{Cov}(Z_i, Z_j) = E[Z_i Z_j] - E[Z_i]E[Z_j] = \pi_{ij} - \pi_i \pi_j.$$
Thus, continuing from above,
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(\delta_S)
&= \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{X_i^2}{\pi_i^2} (\pi_i - \pi_i^2)
+ \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j \ne i} \frac{X_i X_j}{\pi_i \pi_j}(\pi_{ij} - \pi_i \pi_j),
\end{align}
where we have used the linearity rules $\text{Var}(cU) = c^2 \text{Var}(U)$ and $\text{Cov}(aU, bV) = ab\text{Cov}(U, V)$ for variance/covariance.